# Overloaded Declaration Causes Build Error

Tags: typescript, tsc

I have supplied the overloaded declaration for `postMessage` to represent the message-only signature (rather than the lib.d.ts three-argument version).

```
declare function postMessage(message: any): void;
```

I get no visual errors, red squiggles etc, but I do get a build error.

> Build: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
>
> Build: Could not select overload for 'call' expression.

On this line:

```
postMessage(message);
```

Is this a bug in selecting the overload I supplied or am I doing something stupid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a valid bug report for the compler. The following works fine:

```
declare function foo(message: any, targetOrigin: string, ports?: any): void;
declare function foo(message: any): void;

foo('asdf');
```

But the following will error on compile

```
declare function postMessage(message: any): void;
postMessage('asdf');
```

Same for other functions at the root of `lib.d.ts` e.g.:

```
declare function blur(message: any): void;
blur('asdf');
```

It is almost as if the `declare` isn't even parsed. The following gives the same error :

```
postMessage('asdf');
```

## Momentary solution

use the `no-default-lib` reference tag :

```
/// <reference no-default-lib="true"/>
declare function postMessage(message: any): void;
postMessage('asdf');
```

Comment: Cool - I have raised it as a bug: https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2588 - I also tried adding it to the `Window` interface. No joy there either. All works in the Playground so maybe it is already fixed for the next version.

Comment: I believe the error might be in playground as well ... the language service is okay in VS as well (which is what playground is using) + js gets generated by `tsc` as well ... which is what playground is showing on RHS

Answer (score 2):

Temporary work around...

This is the temporary work around for Workers...

```
(function(self: Worker){

    self.postMessage('a');

    self.postMessage({ etc: 'a' });

}(<any>self));
```

Not ideal, but it works because the `Worker` interface has the correct definition of `postMessage` when in `self` context rather than `window` context.